# When the currentTime is changed, its value becomes 0

Tags: javascript, html, django, audio

When the currentTime is changed, its value becomes 0

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audio" style="display: none">
   <source src="" id="audioSource" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div class="time-control" id="progressBar">
   <input id="progress" type="range" style="height: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let audio = document.getElementById('audio');
let progress = document.getElementById('progress');

progress.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   audio.currentTime = (e.offsetX / progress.clientWidth) * audio.duration
}
```

**Values of variables**

[Values of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVy45.png)

Comment: I tested your code and everything worked fine for me, as it should. Maybe the problem is with your audio file, try testing with different ones. I used this for testing: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3. Test with this and see if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Osmar thanks, bro, it worked. I'm uploading a track via a file and it didn't work. I changed the field to url field and I was able to change the current duration

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem!